# How can I store the attributes of objects of an array in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have attributes of objects of an array that I would like to store in an array. Below is my data.

[image: the details]

What I want to do achieve is to store `displays` name attribute in `opt[]` so it would look like this `opt = ['info1', 'info2', 'info3', ... ]`

```
getEditData (id) {

            axios.get('/api/campaign/getEdit/' + id)
                .then(response =>{
                    this.campaign = response.data.campaign;
                })
                .catch(e=>{
                    console.log(e.data);
                    this.error = e.data
                })
        }
```

Above snippet is the source of the campaign object

Comment: Paste PHP code that generates the dump you've shown here.

Comment: Do you want the keys or the values nested under `displays`?

Comment: I want the values @EatPeanutButter

Comment: I have pasted the source @Kyslik

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
campaigns.displays.map( ({name}) => name );
```

```js
const campaigns = { displays: [{ name: 'info1'}, { name: 'info2'}] };

const result = campaigns.displays.map( ({name}) => name );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display an array containing the property names of each object in the `displays` array

```js
    var data = {
      displays: [
        {
          capacity: 9000,
          id: 1,
          imei: 44596
        }
      ]
    };
    data.displays.forEach(function(obj, idx) {
      console.log(Object.keys(obj));
    });
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is what you need

Comment: What I need are the values, not the keys @Sébastien

Comment: The displays array have more than one object. Is this snippet going to loop through the objects?

Comment: Yes, that's what `forEach()` is for, it loops throught each element of an array.